# How to determine Global and Thread Buffer size in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am currently debugging some performance issues related to my cloudsql mySQL database, and am looking to investigate its configuration parameters.

In the cloud sql docs the following note can be found:

> "[Maximum concurrent connections - Note](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#maximum_concurrent_connections):
>
> To determine the maximum value that you can set for this flag, the
> basic formulas are:
>
> `Available RAM = Global Buffers + (Thread Buffers x max_connections)`
>
> `max_connections = (Available RAM - Global Buffers) / Thread Buffers`
>
> To get the list of buffers and their values: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` Allow some headroom for other processes requiring
> memory."

However, running the sql command produces the following output:

```sql
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 55574528       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file     | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 1              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 55574528       |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 16777216       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| key_buffer_size                     | 8388608        |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
25 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I do not understand which values to plug into the formula. Which values correspond to Global Buffers and Thread Buffers?

Comment: Every formula for MySQL's memory usage is flawed.  Some things are per-connection, some are per-query, some are per-subquery, some expand dynamically, etc, etc.  And no one ever hits all the worst cases simultaneously.  So, it is quite normal and safe for a formula to exceed your RAM size even when it is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [blog article](https://www.geekdecoder.com/calculate-mysql-max_connections-variable/) that lists which are the Global Buffer and Thread Buffer variables, which are:

- Global Buffer:

  ```
  key_buffer_size
  innodb_buffer_pool_size
  innodb_log_buffer_size
  innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
  net_buffer_size
  query_cache_size
  ```
- Thread Buffer:

  ```
  sort_buffer_size
  myisam_sort_buffer_size
  read_buffer_size 
  join_buffer_size
  read_rnd_buffer_size
  thread_stack
  ```